# Subtract date and time (PHP)

Tags: php

The format of the date and time is "Y-m-d H: i: s".
I want to subtract the desired time.

```
<?
$set_datetime = "2018-12-03 03:30";
$hour_gap = "8";
?>
```

I want to see the result of subtracting the time ($hour_gap) from the date ($set_datetime) in the format "Y-m-d H: i: s".

Results for: 2018-12-02 19:30

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$set_datetime = "2018-12-03 03:30";
$hour_gap = "8";

date(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s',
    strtotime($set_datetime . ' + '. $hour_gap .' hours')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

> First You Have to Check in Wordpress admin panel setting -> date and time Format. then put this `Y-m-d H: i: s` format there.